# How to plot data points outside the plot region using the matpotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm plotting data points using matplotlib.

Basically, I want to plot discrete points. Many of them are placed on the boundaries. However, as shown in the attached figure, the data points on the figure boundary only appears as a half circle rather than a full circle.

Could anyone suggest how to plot those points on the boundary as full circles?

```
def PlotGrid(grid_point, file_name):
  plt.figure()
  dims = np.shape(grid_point)
  for i in range(0, dims[1]):
    for j in range(0, dims[2]):
      plt.plot(grid_point[0, i, j], grid_point[1, i, j], 'ro',  markersize=15)
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `plt.plot` kwarg `clip_on` to `False`, and the points will show up outside the axes.

```
plt.plot(grid_point[0, i, j], grid_point[1, i, j], 'ro',  markersize=15, clip_on=False)
```

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on):

> `Artist.set_clip_on(b)`
>
> Set whether artist uses clipping.
>
> When False artists will be visible out side of the axes which can lead to unexpected results.
>
> ACCEPTS: [True | False]

Here's a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

ax.plot(0, 0, 'ro', markersize=30, clip_on=True, label='clip_on=True')
ax.plot(1, 1, 'bo', markersize=30, clip_on=False, label='clip_on=False')

ax.legend()    

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Artists can be shown outside the axes by not allowing the axes to clip them, e.g. `plt.plot(..., clip_on=False)`,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5,4)

plt.figure()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(range(4),range(4))
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        plt.plot(X[i,j], Y[i,j], 'ro',  markersize=30, clip_on=False)
plt.margins(0.0)        
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, it might be better to extend the axes range, such that the artist actually lives completely inside the axes. This can be done using `plt.margins()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(range(4),range(4))
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        plt.plot(X[i,j], Y[i,j], 'ro',  markersize=30)
plt.margins(0.1)  ## add 10% margin on all sides      
plt.show()
```

[image]